# Can't read form data from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, http, servlets

I have a simple xmlHttpRequest that submits a DELETE to a servlet.

Here is the JS:

```
        function sendDELETE () {
            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "myServlet";
            var params = "param="+document.getElementById("param").value;
            http.open("DELETE", url, false);

            //Send the proper header information along with the request
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
                if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                }
            }
            http.send(params);
        }
```

This invoked by an onClick event on a button.

Here is what chrome dev tools show:

```
Request URL:http://xxxxxx/myServlet
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:36
Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:xxxxxxxxx
Origin:http://xxxxxxx
Referer:http://xxxxxxxxxxx/main.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview parsed
param=value


Response Headersview source
    Connection:Keep-Alive
    Content-Length:0
    Content-Type:text/html
    Date:Wed, 27 Aug 2014 01:50:10 GMT
    Keep-Alive:timeout=65, max=7998
    Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

By looking at this i can clearly see that the form data has the param=value in the request going OUT

On my server in the `doDelete` I tried two ways:

`String param = req.getParameter("param");` and

`String inputMap = CharStreams.toString(req.getReader());
String [] parts = inputMap.split("=");
String param = parts[1];`

But neither works - the 'param' remains null....

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only POST request have parameters as an entity in the request body. You must send it as part of the URL.

See [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt): "The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the resource identified by the Request-URI".

Comment: Good point, but it seems that several things are at play here. If the parameter is there on the way out (as can be seen in the request) is it being removed by the servlet ? In other words - the RFC specifies how this _should_ be implemented but what\who is actually preventing this parameter from being available to the HttpRequst object ?

Comment: I ended up putting the parameter in the query string - however i still dont understand where or why it was removed from the body...

Comment: It wasn't 'removed from the body'. It just wasn't *looked for* in the body. Request parameters are looked for in the URL, except for POST. This wasn't a POST, and it wasn't a request (such as PUT) that is expected to have a body, so you couldn't get it by reading the body either.

Comment: (1) RFC 2616 is obsolete. (2) Payload format and method names are completely orthogonal concepts. You can use application/x-www-form-urlencoded with any request method that allows a request body (whether it's a good idea is a different question)

Comment: @JulianReschke The evidence here is that `HttpServletRequest` doesn't agree.

Comment: @EJP that would be an implementation bug in the servlet engine (which?)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you aren't doing anything wrong at all.

In HTTP, any request can have a request body (see http://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/specs/rfc7230.html#message.body.length). Also, HTTP doesn't care about the *type* of the payload.

Whether it makes sense to send a payload for DELETE is a separate question; after all, the resource to be deleted needs to be identified by the request URI anyways.

If you can't retrieve the request body in the payload this might be caused by either a bug in the servlet implementation (which is it?), or something between your client and server (proxy? servlet filters?)

Comment: Im using standard Java servlets... I doubt if they have a bug ?

Comment: AFAIU, the Java servlet spec defines an API. What *implementation* of that API are you using?